# How to synchronize planio communication to trello?

Tags: integration, redmine, trello, redmine-api, python-redmine

I am trying to integrate plan.io  with trello so that issue, bug e.t.c communication on planio get synchronized to trello dashboard.

On the internet I am only getting link for redmine to integrate to trello.

Also I found https://zapier.com which only allow to integrate redemine to trello. It doesn't have planio app in their database(searching planio in search bar after login found no result) to link.

Any lead highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Planio](https://plan.io/redmine-hosting/) is based on Redmine and exposes the same [REST API](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api). There’s no official Trello integration (since Planio has its own native agile task boards), but you should be able to use any tool that’s Redmine-compatible with Planio, too. Zapier should work fine.

If something’s not working, please let us know in a support ticket. (I’m the founder of Planio.)